# How do the miners earn money after 2140 on no-transaction-block?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, empty-blocks

A block can embedded no transaction, miner gets no fees for this block.
So, how do the miners earn bitcoin/money after 2140 on no-transaction-block?

thanks,
-baco 
(a back-to-the-future-man from december 2139)

Answer (score 2):

Simple: they don't.

It's not in the best interest of the network for miners to mine zero-transaction blocks.  It means that the transactions in the mempool will have to wait for the next block to be solved before being included.  This phenomenon of blocks with no transactions is a product of the block reward still being so relatively high.  As it decreases, miners will rely more on transaction fees for their incomes, and we will see fewer and fewer zero-transaction blocks.